# Sumif Formula With Multiple Criteria Producing Error

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

**Data Range** is `G106:I114`.

I'm using the below formula:

```
=SUMIFS($H$106:$H$114,$G$106:$G$114,"Apple",$I$106:$I$114,{"Deliver","Cancel"})
```

Result is **123** instead of **246**.

[image]

**NB:** I've tried the above Formula as an Array but even though it produces the same Value.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Wrap it in SUM(), so the Sum remembers the two SUMIF values and sums them together:

```
=SUM(SUMIFS($H$106:$H$114,$G$106:$G$114,"Apple",$I$106:$I$114,{"Deliver","Cancel"}))
```

[image]

Comment: I confusingly deleted my comment while you were replying, because I found your technique works with simpler expression. I confess to testing with LibreOffice, because I don't have easy access a recent version of Excel. It may be a rare incompatibility or bug. Sorry if I caused you an unnecessary investigation.

Comment: @AFH yes this does not work in OpenOffice or Google sheets.

Comment: For such users I'll contribute what does work, namely to sum two separate `SUMIF` expressions: `=SUM(SUMIFS($H$106:$H$114,$G$106:$G$114,"Apple",$I$106:$I$114,"Deliver"),SUMIFS($H$106:$H$114,$G$106:$G$114,"Apple",$I$106:$I$114,"Cancel"))`

Comment: Scott its working once I got in mind to use SUM but didn't. AFH your Formula is lil longer and if it has more bytes more time.